# LED lights won't come on at the same time

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, recessed-lighting

I renovated a kitchen and put in 4 recessed LED lights. They are daisy-chained, 3-way, with an LED compatible dimmer (just one, other switch is just a 3-way switch) When I turn on the lights (from either switch) 2 of the lights don't come on (same 2 every time) When I turn the switch off, the 2 that don't light up flash brightly, then, when I turn the switch on again, all the lights come on. If i turn the lights off and turn them back on within 10 min. they all come on fine, but if I wait longer, the same 2 won't come on, but again, flash, then come on when I turn off/on. Same 2 lights every time. Same pattern every time. HELP!

Comment: Can you link the lights?  Does it behave properly if you replace the dimmer with a plain switch?

Comment: Are those recessed lights rated for dimming?

Comment: Why are you daisy-chaining?  all light fixtures need to be in parallel or certainly things won't work.  Further, you need to make sure your dimmer is in fact designed for 3-way operation.  The quickflash is almost certainly back-EMF, which then pops "live" some solid-state blocking in the fixtures, thus allowing limited power to reach all the fixtures.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft - I think OP is daisy chaining from a topological standpoint - running the cable from one light fixture to the next.  The parallel tap-off for each light would happen inside the fixture,  If OP was doing what you hinted at, each fixture wold only have ~30V across it and the lights probably woudn't come on at all.

Comment: @user7210 - Take out or bypas the dimmer and see if you can control all 4 lights from the remaining switch.

Comment: What make and model are the lights and dimmer in question?

Comment: When i roughed in the lights, everything worked fine (for about 2 weeks, during which period i drywalled and finished the ceiling, of coarse) Everything came on, went off from both switches, dimmer worked great (no flickering). I guess "daisy-chain" is the wrong term?....I just connected one light to another, whatever thats called...          .the lights = https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-Easy-Up-6-in-Deep-Baffle-Color-Selectable-Canless-LED-Recessed-Kit-CER608943K50WH/305320245

Comment: the dimmer= https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-Easy-Up-6-in-Deep-Baffle-Color-Selectable-Canless-LED-Recessed-Kit-CER608943K50WH/305320245

Comment: I came to the site once while drywalling and the dimmer didn't work. I went to the 3 way and the toggle was between on and off. When i fixed that, it was fine....but im not sure for how long after until the flicker issue started happening. Unfortunately, there is a lot of natural light in the kitchen so i didn't always turn on the lights ....